# Apex callout to same org in SandboxPostCopy

Tags: sandbox-refresh

### Use case

During sandbox creation or refresh (Enterprise, not ISV use case), with Apex class implementing `SandboxPostCopy`, invoke MetadataAPI to delete stuff that shouldn't be in the sandbox (like Production Named Credentials)

While Apex can make callouts to the same org including the Metadata API, one needs a sessionId.

### Issue

- Sandbox creation/refresh execute as *Automated Process* user
- UserInfo.getSessionId() as of Winter 19 returns a valid sessionId in async scenarios *but not [if the running user is Automated Process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm?search_text=getSessionId)*
- Publishing a Platform Event and consuming with a Trigger to do the callout won't work because Platform Event subscribers are *Automated Process user*. Same issue if I launched a scheduled class.
- Org is not using MyDomain (yet)
- Any Remote Site Settings inherited by the sandbox from PROD will point at PROD

I can't quite get my head around something to configure in PROD that gets copied into the sandbox during sandbox creation and that Apex would have access to and thus be able to do a callout to the same org without a sessionId that would

- point at `this` sandbox
- be secure

Comment: I tried getting this going using a JWT Auth flow to authenticate a user for the Session ID. Unfortunately couldn't get it to authenticate without having the Consumer Key of the Connected App in the sandbox. Ended up needing to go with the Visualforce page to get this going. Would love to find a secure way to get a Session ID!

Comment: Can you give me a sample snippet of apex class to use metadata api to turn off trigger validation rule?

Comment: @Sudarshan as I stated above, there's no sessionId available to make a call to MDAPI si code won't help.

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for your response.

Comment: Can you share me some snippet i wanted to try metadata api 
not in Post-refresh  step,
As a normal run

Comment: @Sudarshan Go to the examples in the apex MDAPI github repo.  If you get stuck, post a new question with what you have tried.

Comment: if you reaaaally want to do this, a callout does work. Everything needed for the callout (e.g. credentials) can come from Prod, authorization can be against Prod.

Comment: @identigral - I don't follow - if you auth against PROD, the callout to MDAPI would be against PROD, not the new/refreshed sandbox

Comment: @cropredy Authorization is against sandbox with connected app hosted in Prod. SOAP login might work directly against the sandbox, username is mangled but password is the same.

Comment: Re: callouts. There's a KI currently preventing callouts: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwhXAAS/attempting-to-make-http-callouts-from-sandboxpostcopy-class-throws-systemunexpectedexception-attempt-to-release-db-connection-when-not-allowed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way you're going to get this working with SandboxPostCopy. Instead, you'd want to write a batch/shell script, or a Visualforce page that an administrator would need to run once the new org is up and running. This would be the only foolproof way to get everything done that needs to be done.

Comment: Well this is disappointing.  I was looking for a way more likely to happen automatically.  Having an admin do this via a script/VF page is my fallback.

Comment: @cropredy Yeah, you know how much I hate saying "no," but given all the restrictions with SandboxPostCopy, there really isn't an ideal solution here.