# Deactivate all triggers and validation rules as post refresh step?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, deployment-api, mdapideploy, quick-deploy

I have multiple sandbox related to the production org. Currently I wanted to refresh my full copy sandbox, 
There is a way that i can provide an apex class to run post refresh.

The apex class which I am providing will perform dml operation. So I wanted to turn off the triggers, flows, process builders, validation rules.

As I have done through the internet, I found lot for post which use custom setting and labels, but I can't use this because this org code is not built with custom setting switch to turn off and on.

Also came accross tooling api, but all the example I found is to create apex class or trigger.

There is no such example to activate / deactivate the triggers, validation rule.

So now I am looking for a solution to activate / deactivate triggers, validation rules, workflows using apex.

Can somebody help me, Is if possible using apex code?

How do we achieve?

Thank you..

Comment: You have to plan for these things using the various methods you read about in your search on the internet. That means you'll want to create a plan to add custom switches to turn off your validation rules (use custom metadata, not custom settings) and your triggers using a class that controls them with a switch to turn them off/on via custom metadata either individually (lots of work) or all at once (much simpler to implement).

Comment: You might be able to do it through the tooling api in apex. However, if your plan is to do this in a post sandbox refresh script that won't work as your org's api won't be available during that time.

Comment: Post sandbox Apex [callout to same org sadly doesn't work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/apex-callout-to-same-org-in-sandboxpostcopy)