# Sandbox PostCopy script does not fire on refresh

Tags: apex, sandbox, refresh

It sounds like other people out there have made this work, so safe to say mine is not firing due to me doing something wrong although it seems like I'm spot on from the documentation here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm

When I run manually, everything works as expected. Here is what the class looks like:

```
global without sharing class SandboxRefresh implements SandboxPostCopy {
    private boolean isValidContext {
        get {
            if (isValidContext == null) {
                boolean runningInASandbox = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
                boolean isTestContext = test.isRunningTest();
                isValidContext = runningInASandbox || isTestContext;
            }
            return isValidContext;
        }
        set;
    }

    global void runApexClass(System.SandboxContext context) {
        sendIt();
    }

    public void sendIt() {
        // since this would MURDER a production org, we're going to enforce that this only runs in a sandbox or apex test
        if (isValidContext) {
            invlidateCustomLabelEmails(); // invalidates several custom labels with emails in them - uses metadata api 
            invalidateContactEmails(); // fires a batch to invalidate all of the contact emails
            unscheduleJobs(); // aborts all of the scheduled reporting notifications
            indicateRefreshIsComplete(); // updates a custom setting to show that the refresh script ran
        } else {
            throw new SandboxRefreshException('Can only run sandbox scripts in sandbox!');
        }
    }
```

I put "SandboxRefresh" in the "Apex Class" text field on the refresh screen. Never works on refresh, but run it manually after and it works perfectly. Did just realize that I am using a public access modifier and the documentation uses global, so making that switch now and trying a refresh.

Comment: It's worked for me.can you post your code? 
One tip: add real assertions to your test class in case you didn't add already

Comment: what does *"It just doesn't work"* mean? Can you edit your question and demonstrate what you've tried? As written, this isn't actionable.

Comment: It depends on what you expect it to do. The Automated Process user runs the script and limits what you can do. It should be able to update data/custom settings/users just fine though.

Comment: @mark pond - Initially was just seeing if anybody could verify that they have one that works. I had seen there were some known issues related to this functionality that have been resolved, but just wanted to make sure that this is actually functional before digging in to troubleshoot since I only knew of examples where people had similar issues.

Comment: are any of your invalidates calling the metadata API?

Comment: Yes - invlidateCustomLabelEmails uses the metadata API

Comment: Yea, Metadata API calls won't work (or at least, I haven't found a way). As I mentioned, there's limitations because the code executes as Automated Process user. See [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/apex-callout-to-same-org-in-sandboxpostcopy) for a discussion on it. The rest I successfully do use (delete all scheduled reports, update custom settings, fire a batch to update records).