# Add "API Enabled" access to Automated User

Tags: api, sandbox-refresh, sandboxpostcopy

I want to create `Profile Login Api Range`  during sandbox creation or refresh.
I'm using `SandboxPostCopy` interface and [Metadata Service](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls).

I saw something similar in this question : [sandboxpostcopy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/apex-callout-to-same-org-in-sandboxpostcopy)

However, I am having some troubles with it. I have already figured out how to get `Session Id` (using Visualforce Page).
Now I am stuck with the following error :

> Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: API_CURRENTLY_DISABLED: API is disabled for this User faultcode=sf:API_CURRENTLY_DISABLED

As I understand it, `Automated User` does not have access to `API Enabled` permission.

I have already tried to create a Permission Set and assign it to `Automated User` in an Execute Anonymous window but got an error

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, The user license doesn't allow the permission: ApiEnabled: []

Also, I tried to assign a Permission Set to the User and the add the permission, but got this error

> Can't save permission set Api enabled, which is assigned to a user with user license Automated Process. The user license doesn't allow the permission: API Enabled

So is there a way to create `Profile Login Api ranges` from `SandboxPostCopy` class ?

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same wall here. I ran out of time and energy trying some workaround to that in the SandboxPostCopy script, but without success.

What am I doing now: I created a common apex class, and I run it manually after the refreshes.

I does not deliver the automation I was looking for, but it works, and it certainly is easier and more practical than doing manually. You could somehow automate this class call if you set up some ci/cd using GitLab (I did not arrive at this point yet).

I know that this is not the answer you were looking for, but that's what I got. Good luck there!

Comment: thanks for answer!
I also thinking about some writing some code and run it manually after the refreshes.